# Push menu option greyed out in EGit

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

This is with EGit 3.0.1 on Eclipse 4.2.1.

I created a new project in and made a first commit. I then created a new repo at GitHub to push this project there. Unfortunately the `Push` option in the Team menu (project name right click) is greyed out:

[image]

How should I push this new project to GitHub? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way to get your existing eclipse project working with Github if you get to much struggle using egit.

1. Create new repo at github through browser
2. Create a new dir where you want your project to reside
3. Clone the repo to this directory

   - navigate there through terminal `cd /path/to/dir`
   - Clone: git clone https://this.url.is.found.at.github.in.the.right.side.of.the.repo.site
4. move your code to the directory through terminal or explorer like application
5. Add the content to git version control: `git add .`   (. means add all files)
6. Commit to local repo: `git commit -m "you commit message"` (stand in the newly created dir as in 4)
7. Push to github: `git push origin master` (stand in the newly creted dir as in 4)
8. From eclipse: create new project from existing source and select your created directory

Have fun:)

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "create a new map". Besides that, I'd prefer to use EGit, I'm already familiar with the `git` command.